# extends BroadcastReceiver onReceive function Can't get static ArrayList from other class

Tags: android, arraylist, broadcastreceiver, static-variables

This the receiver

```
    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
      {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");

        wl.acquire();

 NotificationClass.createNotification("Total Item In List is :"+Globals.productList.size(),context);
        wl.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        Log.i("ALARM", "Alarm has been set it");
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 1 * 1, pi); 

    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Log.i("ALARM","Alarm has been Cancel");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
```

Here Is Global Class

```
public class Globals  {
  public static List <ProductClass> productList=new ArrayList<ProductClass>();
public static String testArray[]={"test1","test2","test3"};
}
```

App didn't crash but onReceive function Globals.productList.size return 0,I can get data from testArray. 
the productList arraylist is also static and I can get data from Globals.ProductList in all activity except onReceuve function.

So, How can I reach and get data from Global static ArrayList ?

MainActivity class

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            GetDataClass.getAllData();
  List <ProductList> pList=new ArrayList<ProductList>();
                pList=GetDataClass.data;
        for(int i=0;i<GetDataClass.data.size();i++)
        {

            ProductList temp=new ProductList();

            temp.set(pList.get(i).pName,pList.get(i).stock,
                    pList.get(i).provider,pList.get(i).jk,pList.get(i).starCounter);

            Globals.productList.add(temp);
        }
        Log.i("Count", String.valueOf(Globals.productList.size()));//Return Correct number.

   Alarm alarm=new Alarm();
    alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: There is no point of declaring `pList` and `temp` inside the loop, just declare them outside the scope and initialise them inside the loop to `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to debug this and watch the changes to your `productList`.

From a first look without the rest of the code, I believe on the program start you initialise your list as a new list which creates an empty list of size 0 *(Which is being returned to you)* so this for me looks quite normal.

The `BroadcastReceiver` should be called as follow, you don't create object of it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, alarmRequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarTime, pendingIntent);
```

Check `BroadcastReceiver` documentation for more details.

** Note that saving data to a static list doesn't mean they will stay there after the program is closed, and `BroadcastReceiver` could be running while the app is not running that's why you will be able to retrieve the data in the application and not in this class. Maybe you would need to save the data in a database or something to be able to reach it, I believe your problem is here not in the way of retrieving the data. *(Again a bit more of code would help me to help you better)*

Comment: I have initialise productList in MainActivity

















  ProductList temp=new ProductList();
        temp.set("test1",123,"test","test",5);
        Globals.productList.add(temp);

Comment: and i can get that list from other activities

Comment: And when is the `BroadcastReceiver` called?

Comment: You need to debug to check the list size at this time the `BroadcastReceiver` is called. But another approach could be passing the `size` as `ExtraInt` to the intent calling the receiver and retrieve the size from there, however that will help if you only need the size of the list and nothing else

Comment: after getting the size I will list items too

Comment: You need to set your alarms in the `MainActivity` not in a method inside the receiver itself, again this might not solve your problem as static list don't save data in all the cycle of the application, maybe you can try to initialise the `productList` on receive instead/again